# Transfer domain from one registrar to another, with privacy

Tags: domains, privacy, domain-registrar

I want to transfer a domain from one [domain name registrar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar) to another, without revealing my contact information.

I use [domain privacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_privacy) services.  The registrars tell me I need to disable domain privacy on the originating registrar before initiating the transfer.  This will expose my personal information (address, email address) publicly in Whois.  Unfortunately, I know that there are operations who regularly crawl Whois data and archive it and later allow people to search those historical archives of Whois information, so disabling domain privacy for even a few days or weeks is enough that it might expose my private information forever after.  I don't want that.

Is there any way to transfer a domain name between registrars, without exposing my personal information to the public?

Comment: Domain transfers can be done pretty quick these days, even in a matter of a few hours or minutes sometimes. I'd suggest getting familiar with the transfer steps for both registrars by reviewing their FAQ on transfers, then disable the domain privacy just prior to initiating the transfer, look for the authentication emails and respond to them. If you added privacy with the new registrar, you should be fine since most WHOIS database collectors scan for _new_ registrations.

Comment: Domain transfers require approval (usually by a live person?) from the prior registrar so it can take a day just for that.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered changing your private info before disabling the protection? You could try renting a P.O. box during the transition to use (or equivalent if outside the US) so that your personal address is not exposed. Similar, you can use a disposable email to prevent your personal email from being exposed. Once the transfer is complete, you can change the info back.

Answer (score 2):

If the previous (current at the time) registrar's privacy service forwards email sent to the account in the domain registration then it might be possible to do the transfer without disabling privacy.

The new registrar will send an "approval request" (that is what GoDaddy calls it) to the previous (current at the time) registrar. If the privacy service of the previous (current at the time) registrar forwards the "approval request" then you will probably be able to do the transfer without disabling privacy. Many privacy services do not forward messages so that is (probably?) why privacy must be disabled for them.